# Why do I see MS jQuery samples use `$(domReady); `?

Tags: jquery, syntax, sample

I don't know if anyone ELSE has noticed this, but I noticed the [jQuery samples I see on MS](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx) tend to use a different format:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

  $( domReady );  

  function domReady() {  
     $('#btn').click( showMessage );  
  }  

  function showMessage() {  
     $('#message').fadeIn('slow');  
  }  
</script>
```

Isn't this the same as:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  $('#btn').click( showMessage );  

  function showMessage() {  
     $('#message').fadeIn('slow');  
  }  

});
```

Is there any advantage of using one syntax over the other?

I will admit, the MS way does look cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real difference is readability and organization.

It's technically the same as

```
$( function() {

  $('#btn').click( showMessage );  

  function showMessage() {  
     $('#message').fadeIn('slow');  
  }  

});
```

which is shorthand for `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: I've always wondered how that shorthand works. `$(document).ready(...)` I understand. I guess jQuery is expecting a delegate or anonymous function?

Comment: The main jQuery function $() checks to see if the typeof the parameter is a function.  If it is, it adds it as an event handler to document.ready.  If it is something else it uses it as a selector.

I think this is what actually does it:

    if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
        return rootjQuery.ready( selector );
    }