# jquery document ready handler

Tags: jquery

Is there any difference between using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

vs.

```
$(function(){
```

Does one of these work better than the other in some way, or is the first just a shorthand version of the first?

Comment: Is the same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625220/why-do-i-see-ms-jquery-samples-use-domready ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384204/is-there-a-difference-between-ready-and-document-ready

Comment: You should read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10753306/601179)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The latter is the short version of ready handler.

The:

```
$(function(){

})
```

is short version of this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

}
```

Both do the same and one task.

jQuery is doing to a good deal with its slogan:

**'Code less, do more'**

Comment: @dclowd9901: I didn't know about you either. OP definitely needed to know about it.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> All three of the following syntaxes
>   are equivalent:
>
> ```
> * $(document).ready(handler)
> * $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
> * $(handler)
> ```
>
> There is also
>   $(document).bind("ready", handler).
>   This behaves similarly to the ready
>   method but with one exception: If the
>   ready event has already fired and you
>   try to .bind("ready") the bound
>   handler will not be executed.
>
> The .ready() method can only be called
>   on a jQuery object matching the
>   current document, so the selector can
>   be omitted.

HTH